# How to create a dictionary where the dictionary value is a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I iterate over the below list of dictionaries

```
  test_dict = {'key1': [{'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'},
                                 {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}]}
    print(type(test_dict.values()))
    for value in test_dict.values() :
        print('value is' , value)
```

the output is :

```
value is [{'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'}, {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}]
```

I expect the output to be :

```
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'}
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}
```

I've also tried explicitly adding dictionaries to a list :

```
values_list = []
values_list.append({'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'})
values_list.append({'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'})
test_dict = {'key1': values_list}
```

but the result is same

How to create a dictionary where the dictionary value is a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: `for value in test_dict.values() : for each_value in value: ...`

Comment: The key-value pairs begin like this `'key1': [...` -- a list, not a dictionary to the right of the colon. In this case you seem to have only a single value to the overall dictionary.

Comment: You say right in the title: "value is a list of dictionaries". Why do you expect anything other than a list in the values?

Comment: Why do you expect that? Your dictionary has a single key-value pair, and that value is a list.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary definition is fine, but you have to address every element in the list:

```
test_dict = {'key1': [{'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'},
                      {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}]
            }

for value in test_dict.values(): # value is a list here
    for element in value:
        print('value is' , element)
```

Output:

```
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'}
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Code:

```
test_dict = {'key1': [{'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'},{'k2': 'f', 'k3': 
'', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}]}


for value in test_dict['key1'] :
    print('value is' , value)
```

Output:

```
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'No'}
value is {'k2': 'f', 'k3': '', 'k4': 'b', 'k5': 'Yes'}
```